# LPC1347 group level interrupt clearing

Tags: lpc

I'm using LPC1347 board which has two group interrupts. I'd like to write simple program which uses only one pin group interrupt (for testing only). Edge interrupts works well but when I change interrupt type to low level sensitive (or / and - it doesn't matter) I can't clear interrupt status so the program is stucked in the ISR... Writing one to CTRL register has not effect. Is a different way of clearing level group interrupts?

Answer (score 0):

> change interrupt type to low level sensitive

Level interrupts are always (re-)triggered when the pin is in the selected state - low in your case. You can either mask the interrupt bit or change the level to high (or to rising edge) in the interrupt handler.

So in a nutshell, you need to turn off the interrupt source, or the interrupt handler will tail-chained into and thus run in a loop as long as the pin is in the low state.